# Force the execution of a method in a class

Tags: java

I'm using Java and I want to call the method f2 in class A from the class B. Is it possible to do this?

```
public class A{
  private B b = new B();

  public void f1(){
    b.f3();
  }

  public void f2(){
    // do something;
  }
}

public class B{
  public void f3(){
    // Call f2 of class A from here.
  }

}
```

Comment: Well yes, so long as you have an instance of `A` on which to call it...

Comment: I assume you want to call the instance which called it, not just any `A` instance?

Comment: @Peter Lawrey true. That is so

Comment: @user1448906: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17193141/45914) addresses that scenario for you. See the last code sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an instance of `A` in class `B` and invoke `f2` on that instance. For example, you could instantiate one inside the body of `f3`:

```
public class B {
    public void f3() {
        A a = new A();
        a.f2();
    }
}
```

Another way would be for `f3` to receive an instance of `A`:

```
 public class B {
    public void f3(A a) {
        a.f2();
    }
 }
```

And yet another way, you could have `B` instantiate one:

```
public class B {
    private final A a;
    public B() { this.a = new A(); }
    public void f3() {
         this.a.f2();
    }
}
```

And lastly, `B` could receive one in it's constructor:

```
 public class B {
     private final A a;
     public B(A a) { this.a = a; }
     public void f3() {
         this.a.f2();
     }
 }
```

The point being that if you want to invoke an instance method on a class **you must have an instance of that class in your hand**.

Finally, I notice that you have `A.f1` invoking `B.f3` and from there you want to invoke `A.f2`. So, it looks like your best option here is the *second* option above. That is:

```
public class A {
    private final B = new B();
    public void f1() { this.b.f3(this); }
    public void f2() { /* do something */ }
}

public class B {
    public void f3(A a) { a.f2(); }
}
```

The key here is that we are passing an instance of `A` to `B.f3`. The way that we achieve that is by passing the `this` reference, which is a reference to the currently executing instance. In `A.f1`, that would be the instance of `A` that is currently executing.

Answer (score 1):

You need an instance of class A to do this.

```
public class A{
  private B b = new B();

  public void f1(){
    b.f3(this);
  }

  public void f2(){
    // do smthing;
  }
}

public class B{
  public void f3(A a){
    a.f2(); // Call f2 of class A from here.
  }    
}
```

This type of code structure is usually more confusing than useful.  I suggest instead doing this.

```
public class A{
  private B b = new B();

  public void f1(){
    WhatAf2Needs w = b.f3();
    f2(w);
  }

  public void f2(WhatAf2Needs w){
    // do smthing;
  }
}

public class B{
  public WhatAf2Needs f3(A a){
    return WhatAf2Needs;
  }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call a method of the thing that called you, you have to have the caller pass itself in using the `this` keyword. In code, it would be:

```
public class A{
  private B b = new B();

  public void f1(){
    b.f3(this);
  }

  public void f2(){
    // do smthing;
  }
}

public class B{
  public void f3(A caller){
    caller.f2();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to instantiate class `A` in class `B`, given the way it's currently written, to make any method calls on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also declare `f2` static and call it like `A.f2()`. This type of things depend a lot on the design of your classes though. The other answers here are very valid too.

```
public class A{
  private B b = new B();

  public void f1(){
    b.f3();
  }

  public static void f2(){
    // do smthing;
  }
}

public class B{
  public void f3(){
    A.f2();
  }

}
```

Comment: that is not possible to make f2 static

Comment: You can add that to your question. As I said, there a lot of ways of doing it depending on your class and program design.

Comment: that's true. But guess, I've already found the the solution that fits me.